# Spotify apps api inspector not working

Tags: spotify

I'm looking at the spotify apps api. When I try to open the inspector it says "Please select the app to inspect". Selecting or loading an app does not help, I always get this message, on any app. I have a developer account and am using version 0.8.10.2.g1283206d, I also tried older versions. I'm on Windows 7. Did anyone get this error? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can not inspect other peoples apps. It only seems to work on apps you have loaded from your local machine.

Comment: Did you right click on the app and choose from the context menu, or access from the top menu. I find I get that error when I choose from the top menu and did not have my last focus in the application. Just having the app active doesn't seem to be enough.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but found a solution

So apparently it works for me, if you right-click the open application and hit "Show Inspector". After that, it works to hit show inspector from the top menu bar as well. However as soon as you go to another app at switch back to your local app, you're once again not able to hit "show inspector" from the top menu bar. Seems like there is a bug in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try right-clicking the app itself and choosing "Show Inspector" from the pop-up menu you get.

Comment: I don't have that option in the popup-menu. Something must be missing on my system. I tried reinstalling spotify, but doesn't help.

Comment: You can only inspect local apps.